# How to specify schema for Postgres in Golang?

Tags: go

I have a database that stores customer data in different schemas(schema per tenant). I need to be able to dynamically set the schema name upon the execution of a query. My problem is that I run those queries upon a web request using gin, and I have multiple threads running at the same time. So basically doing this

```
_, err = db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("set search_path to %s", schemaName))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// GAP

var queryStr = "select * from customer_data"

query, err := db.Query(queryStr)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer query.Close()
```

works fine when executed in a single thread environment, but from a web server perspective, that's too unreliable, because I can end up requesting data from customer 1 and getting from customer 2, because during the GAP specified in the code, the other thread can call `set search_path` query.

Comment: You could cache db connections per tenant, use transactions, or use the schema names in the SQL statements like `<schema_name>.<table_name>`.

Comment: Using schema names in SQL statements leads to really unreadable statements that contain a lot of `%s.table_name` expressions, and using transactions on a select statement seems kind of a workaround. I was thinking about having multiple connections, but that could lead to the database becoming a bottleneck soon.

Comment: Is there a nice way to inject the `<schema_name>.` part to an SQL statement?

Answer (score 0):

As @rsp comments, you can qualify table names by their schema (eg `schema1.customer_data`) or use transactions.

There are plenty of reasons to want to separate databases into schemas and many, many reasons for using transactions.

A good writeup about using transactions for `database/sql` is the [Go Blog article "Executing transactions"](https://go.dev/doc/database/execute-transactions).

An example transaction block might look something like the following ( note there is no error checking, or checks for `sql.ErrNoRows` situations):

```golang
// transact runs a set of SQL statements in a transaction
func transact(db *sql.DB, schema string) {

    fmt.Println("transacting for schema:", schema)

    // start a transaction
    ctx := context.Background()
    tx, err := db.BeginTx(ctx, nil)
    panicOnErr("tx setup", err)

    // defer a rollback in case anything fails
    defer tx.Rollback()

    schemaSet(tx, schema) // set the schema
    inserter(tx, "user1", 5) // insert some data
    inserterQuery(tx, "user2", 7) // insert and return data
    lister(tx) // list data

    // explicit rollback
    err = tx.Rollback()
    panicOnErr("rollback err", err)
}
```

A fuller example is available [here](https://gist.github.com/rorycl/3530b06c3d5a04c7c055fb9ea7b408db).